# How to apply bootstrap v4 alpha's form input validation classes with ASP.NET Razor syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

So, bootstrap v4 alpha has changed form validation classes a bit. Now, to apply validation styles to a form input, you apply the CSS class to the parent `div.form-group`.

I'm writing a website using ASP.NET MVC4, and am trying to figure out how to apply this CSS class to a parent HTML element.

For example, here's my current HTML for a form input element ...

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
</div>
```

If my view's model has a validation error for the `Password` field, it'll get a corresponding bit of text below the input field. That's what that `ValidationMessageFor` call does.

But, with bootstrap v4, I need to apply a `has-danger` class to the parent `div.form-group`. It'd need to look like so ...

```
<div class="form-group has-danger">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
</div>
```

But, I only want to apply that if there is a validation message for the password field.

Any idea how to achieve this with Razor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an `HtmlHelper` that checks `ModelState` and returns an error class:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string FieldHasError(this HtmlHelper helper, string propertyName, string errorClass = "has-danger")
    {            
        if (helper.ViewData.ModelState != null && !helper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValidField(propertyName))
        {
            return errorClass;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public static string FieldHasError<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, string errorClass = "has-danger")
    {
        var expressionString = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var modelName = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(expressionString);
        return FieldHasError(helper, modelName, errorClass);
    }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
<div class="form-group @Html.FieldHasError("Password")">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="form-group @Html.FieldHasError(m => m.Password)">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
</div>
```

Comment: Very cool idea! I've never thought about doing this sort of thing. Thanks.