# How to apply bootstrap v4 form input validation classes with the ASP.NET Razor syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

The following code:

**View:(is-valid)**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Telefone, new { @class = "font-weight-bold" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Telefone, new { @class = "form-control is-valid", @placeholder = "Digite seu telefone" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Telefone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

**View:(is-invalid)**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Telefone, new { @class = "font-weight-bold" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Telefone, new { @class = "form-control is-invalid", @placeholder = "Digite seu telefone" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Telefone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Example: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#server-side

Any solution ?

Comment: This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387981/2588539

Answer (score 10):

The class name is hardcoded: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.1.6/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/HtmlHelper.cs#L25

The only option is to alter  CSS.

When you build Bootstrap from sources you can just add the next code into your SCSS file:

```
.input-validation-error {
  @extend .is-invalid;
}
```

This will create an alias for existing .is-invalid.

Comment: For those searching, this works with .NET 5 and Bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 8):

Simple solution by using Tag Helpers:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control">
            <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display:block;">
                <span asp-validation-for="Email"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What if you want to change the Input box itself using the is-vailid or is-invalid so it shows green or red? "<input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" >"

Answer (score 0):

Razor uses jQuery validation. You only need to hock jq-valid with Bootstrap:

```
$('form').validate().settings.errorClass += ' is-invalid';
$('form').validate().settings.validClass += ' is-valid';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//CONFIGURACAO BOOTSTRAP 4 PARA JQUERY VALIDATION PLUGIN
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    onfocusout: function (e) {
        this.element(e);
    },
    //onkeyup: false,
    highlight: function (element) {
        jQuery(element).closest('.form-control').addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        jQuery(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('is-invalid');
        jQuery(element).closest('.form-control').addClass('is-valid');
    },

    errorElement: 'div',
    errorClass: 'invalid-feedback',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group-prepend').length) {
            $(element).siblings(".invalid-feedback").append(error);
            //error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: verbal explanations are often very helpful in answers

Answer (score -1):

Building off Seagull's answer for .Net 5 and Bootstrap 5 (I can't comment on his answer).

I was able to follow this guide, https://www.dotnetcatch.com/2019/05/16/adding-bootstrap-sass-to-asp-net-core/, to build a custom Bootstrap CSS that includes the ASP.NET validation class name so that you get the look of the Bootstrap validation controls.

```
@import "../lib/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

.input-validation-error {
    @extend .is-invalid;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

be sure to include :
"jquery .js
jquery.validate .js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive .js"